# Java Runtime Error While Deploying SWF to IPA

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, deployment, flash, ipa

I'm trying to make a mobile app with Flash Builder 4 using the AIR 2.6 SDK. Everything works fine on Windows, even on Android. But while compiling the SWF to an IPA file for iOS I get a Java Runtime Error. I'm using command prompt to deploy the SWF out of the released build with external libraries.

This succeed. But when I make an IPA of it by using this command line in the bin-release folder it gives a java runtime error.

```
"C:\temp\AdobeAIRSDKlatest\bin\adt" -package -target ipa-ad-hoc -provisioning-profile
Tims_provisioning_profile.mobileprovision -storetype pkcs12 -keystore iphone_dev.p12
testapplication01.ipa Main-app.xml Main.swf
```

**We're using Xverbose to watch every step of the deployment. Is it possible to add some params to Xverbose, so I can see some more detailed information about the compiling code.**

[image: Xverbose]
[image: Xverbose(2)]
[image: Runtime Error]

I hope someone can help me here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ooo, I love playing the error guessing game!

Comment: Indeed there is not even a decent explanation. I think it will take hours to put everything into comment and run it line by line..